# Question on Notation (with respect to a sequence of functions)

Tags: analysis

What does " $\sup_{n \geq 1} |f_n|^2$ is summable" mean?

Comment: Being "summable" means that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty |f(k)|<\infty$.  So, if $\hat{f} = \sup_{n\geq 1}|f_n|^2$, this is just saying that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty |\hat{f}(k)|<\infty$.

Comment: No,  "summable" is usually meant as a synonym for "Lebesgue integrable" (on whatever domain is being considered).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Thanks!